# MVC Repository pattern with services - how to get errors on DAL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

So I have a method in my service, which I will call from a controller:

```
public void SendMessage(Message message) {
        message.Property = "Random";
        try { 
            // try some insert logic
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            // if it fails undo some stuff
            // return the errors 
            throw;
        }

        // if there are no errors on the return the operation was a success
        // but how do I get the Service generated data?
    }
```

**Edit:**

So the question isn't really about getting my code to work it's a problem I have with the **Repository Pattern** whilst using a **Service Layer** as a 'go between' for communication between the **DAL** and **Presentation**

So I have a separate assembly called `DataLibrary`.

The `DataLibrary` has my models (`Message`), my repositories and Services (`MessageService`)

In my MVC site I would typically have a controller, with CRUD functionality. It would look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Message message) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.insert(message);
    }
    Return View(message);
}
```

But by using the Repository Pattern, with a service layer for communication I have this instead:

```
public ActionResult Create(MessageCreateModel message) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        MessageService.SendMessage(message.ToDTO());
    }
    Return View(message);
}
```

How do I know that the operation was successful or unsuccessful and for what reason?

How do I retrieve the populated data from the service's business logic at the same time as the above?

And how do I achieve both of these two above while sticking as close as possible to MVC design pattern / spearation of concerns for extensibility?

Comment: Just to clarify, the service layer, repos and DTOs are wrapped up inside of a separate assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why do you go through as service if it's just delegating the work to your repository? If you have implemented your repository properly (i.e. being a complete abstraction) there is no need to use the service. Simply call the repository directly from your controller. You can read more about the repository pattern in my [blog](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/).

But that doesn't really adress the issue.

So how do you handle errors? When it comes to exceptions: [***Simply do not catch it***](http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/do-not-catch-that-exception/) ;) [Exceptions are after all exceptions](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/04/what-is-exceptions/#.UX7TG7VpnCY) and is not something that you typically can handle to deliver the expected result.

As we are talking about the data layer that usually means a stable database engine where it's expected that the read/write will succeed. Hence there is no need for any other error handling than using exceptions.

In ASP.NET MVC you can handle transactions with an attribute and use try/catch to fill the model state as shown [here](http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/how-to-handle-transactions-in-asp-net-mvc3/):

```
[HttpPost, Transactional]
public virtual ActionResult Create(CreateModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    try
    {
        model.Category = model.Category ?? "Allmänt";

        var instruction = new Instruction(CurrentUser);
        Mapper.Map(model, instruction);
        _repository.Save(instruction);

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = instruction.Id});
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        // Adds an error to prevent commit.
        ModelState.AddModelError("", err.Message);
        Logger.Error("Failed to save instruction for app " + CurrentApplication, err);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've read your blog post, I have a similar problem to the first poster there. I have business logic I feel should go into a service layer because I need to use refs to various models/repos in one single place (other than the controller). If I'm instead inserting a User, how do I return a 'User already exists error'?

Comment: Makes total sense now, my apologies for late response. if it works return the Object, else I can throw and catch my own errors internally and validate against that :)

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't provide enough information about your architecture is structured to answer this question.  However, if you want to get a value back from the `SendMessage` method, adding a return value instead of `void` is a good place to start.

Comment: Haha. Nice response. I was looking for a bit of theory that I could then go off and research. I hope my edit has shed some light on what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first decide how are you going to design your architecture. Are you go with service oriented, if so your service methods have to be return something for inform controllers. So think your service layer like a border of a country, and the other country's borders are controllers. And you have to let trade these two countries. This can be done with return object which contains return data and also service errors and so on.

If you only want to put your some business logic into your service layer then you probably dont need independent layers. Just some loose coupling is enough for you. So you can return basic clr objects or domain objects or application objects. In a very basic example like this:

```
//AService service method
public AnEntity ServiceMethod(AFilterViewModel aFilter)
{
     //do some validation
     try
     {
          //some transactional operations
     }
     catch
     {
          //do some log and rollback it... 
          throw;
     }
     var anEntity = _aRepository.GetSomeEntity(x=> x.Something == aFilter.Something);
     return anEntity;
}

//controller method
public ActionResult GetSomething(AFilterViewModel aFilter)
{
     try
     {
          var entity = _aService.ServiceMethod(aFilter);
          AViewModel model = MapToView(entity);
          return View(model);
     }
     catch
     {
          return RedirectToAction("Error");
     }
}
```

As you see above the controller and service layer methods can share each others objects. They have boundaries to each other and they coupled. But your architecture decides how much they coupled.

You can also do these mappings one way only. Something like service to Controller only or Controller to service only. If you dont want to use your viewmodel in service layer, you should always do mappings in service layer. Otherwise do your object mapping in controllers.  And also dont forgot to put your viewmodel's into another library, its very important. These are something like "value objects".